# How to get all images have in S3 using Nodejs (API). I don't have Key

Tags: node.js

This is my function. I cannot get list image from S3

```
async getList(request) {
    request.Bucket = this.bucket;
    const res = await this.s3.getObject(request).promise();
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, first get [list of buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listBuckets-property), then for each bucket, get its [list of objects (which including keys)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property)